# find lastindexof not working in file path string

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the starting point of the file name from the string below.

I don't get any errors but _lastSlash are not set either.  Does anyone see why the last line will not work.

```
 line = Test\Folder\Machine_Initialization.txt

 using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(_fileList))
 {
    string line;
    int _lastSlash;

    while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       _lastSlash = line.LastIndexOf("\\");
    }
```

I edited the question.  I had a _fileName = Path.GetFileName(line) in earlier but it was not working so I took it out of the question.

If you step through the debugger after the _lastSlash = line.LastIndexOf("\") you see "_lastSlash  The name '_lastSlash' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Are you sure the lines in the stream all have backslashes. Also, you make mention of `_filename` variable that isn't in your code.

Comment: And this is not how you extract file name from path.…

Comment: Please check whether you are reading the correct file, whether this line is really in the file, and whether the line has backslashes

Comment: a very simple thing you can do, is put a breakpoint at the `_lastSlash` that is inside the while loop and see the value of it, or simple make it print to the console or textbox depending on what you're using to see its content and ensure you have the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the static [`System.IO.Path` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for file name manipulations.

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(myPath);
string file = Path.GetFileName(myPath);
```

There also methods `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(...)` and `Path.GetExtension(...)` and methods to combine parts: `Path.Combine(dir, filename)` and many more.

Comment: I tried that first and it did not work.  I thought it was because the string "line" is read in by stream.ReadLine() and not actually from a file dialog.

Comment: It does not matter where the string comes from. A string is a string. Inspect the string in the debugger and see what it actually contains. The error might be somewhere else. Note that in the debugger single backslashes are displayed as escaped (i.e. they appear as \\\). See: [Getting Started with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The reason `Path.GetFileName(line)` is not working for you is because you are not using the right escape sequence.

Please try either of this to get the desired result.

```
line = @"Test\Folder\Machine_Initialization.txt"
```

or

```
line = "Test\\Folder\\Machine_Initialization.txt"
```

Comment: The string is an example of the line in the file that op is reading. There is no need for any different formatting. If you look at the code you can see that `line` is overwritten with each reading command. It would not make any sense to initiate it in the beginning